# How can I add multiple Metadata in Torch Tensorboard Embedding?

Tags: python, pytorch, metadata, tensorboard

I am using `torch==1.9.0` and `tensorboard==2.5.0`. I would like to track data with tensorbaord as an embedding, so I am something like this:

```
data = np.random.poisson(lam=10.0, size=(4,4))
labels = ["A","A","B","B"]
ids = [1,2,3,4]
writer = SummaryWriter("/runs/")
writer.add_embedding(data,
                    metadata=labels)
writer.close()
```

But I only can add lables or ids as metadeta and not a combined dictionaty `{'ids':ids, 'lables':labels}`. Any idea, how to solve this? Thanks!

FYI: Tensorboard docs just descirbes metadata as a list:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer. You could get multiple fields by adding a metadata header and give metadata as list of lists:

```
writer.add_embedding(data.values,
                    metadata=metadata,
                    metadata_header=["Name","Labels"])
```

Reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/61

The format should be so that `metadata[0]` contains one of each metadata field. You can do that with `metadata=list(zip([names, labels]))` if you already have two lists `names` and `labels`.

Comment: Hi, can you give me an example? I tried setting metadata to: [name, labels] while name and labels are both lsits and it gives me the AssertionError: #labels should equal with #data points error

Comment: @Fenrir the problem lies [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py#L976) The source code of [make_tsv](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/utils/tensorboard/_embedding.py#L28) here makes it clear that the format of the metadata "list of lists" is actually the other way around than what you and I first tried. In thogaertner's example, it'd be `metadata=[["Alice", "A"], ["Bob", "B"]]`, not `metadata = [names, labels]`. The fix is to do `metadata=list(zip([names, labels]))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate over the appropriate Metadata (dictionary) to add all the values:

```
writer = SummaryWriter("/runs/")

for i in range(len(data)):
     writer.add_embedding(data[i], metadata=labels[i], global_step=ids[i])

writer.close()
```

*whereas `data`, `labels` and `ids` are the values specified by you above.*

As described in the appropriate [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html?highlight=add_embedding#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_embedding) - `.add_embedding(...)` would also take `label_img` for each datapoint, but you didn't specify it: So, just adding the data matrix and the appropriate labels can be achieved via iterating and accessing the appropriate labels.

Answer (score 0):

A working example was found here: https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX/pull/110 by user h0rm

```
dataset = datasets.MNIST('mnist', train=True, download=True)
images_train = dataset.train_data[:100].float()
labels_train = dataset.train_labels[:100]
features_train = images_train.view(100, 784)

all_features = torch.cat((features, features_train))
all_labels = torch.cat((label, labels_train))
all_images = torch.cat((images, images_train))
dataset_label = ['test']*100 + ['train']*100
all_labels = list(zip(all_labels, dataset_label))

writer.add_embedding(all_features, metadata=all_labels, 
label_img=all_images.unsqueeze(1),
                 metadata_header=['digit', 'database'])
```